# addCookie() not working in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cookies

Currently I am in the process to migrate my application from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7. In my flow there is a part to add cookie from servlet to jsp in a method of servlet. But neither it is adding the cookie nor it is throwing any exception. To cross check it I have tried to add cookie within the jsp forcefully. But got the same result.

servlet.java

```
public void logon( String username, String password, String ip, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception, LogonFailure {
    System.out.println(" Input Received ::"+response);
        System.out.println("Attachment :::"+getNextAttachment());

        AuthenticatorTicketWrapper wrapper = new AuthenticatorTicketWrapper( username, password, ip, "" + getNextAttachment(), this );

        // if no exception thrown then we must of managed to log on.
        String userID =  "" + this.getNextID();
        System.out.println("User Id within Logon method ::"+userID);
        wrapper.setUserName(userID);
        //wrapper.set

        m_Cache.put( userID, wrapper );
        // add cookie to the users browser



        try {
            System.out.println("Cookiename in the logon method :"+cookieName);
            response.addCookie( new Cookie(this.cookieName + this.CREATION_ID, userID) );
            response.addCookie( new Cookie(this.cookieName + this.CREATION_KEY, wrapper.getUserCookieKey() ) );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Failed Add cookie, Exception " + se);
        }


    }
```

catalina.policy

```
// Permission the examples/samples - see the context xml files
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/CreationWeb/-" {
      permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Can you please let me know if I am missing anything?

Comment: from where `cookieName` came & where it's defined ?

Comment: `setMaxAge()` will help you I think.. try that before `response.addCookie();`

Comment: cookieName is coming from a global variable . I have checked using debugger and that is coming. let me check with setMaxAge().

Comment: okay, something like this : `cookie.setMaxAge(60*60); //1 hour`

Answer (score 0):

I've previously used code such as the following to set cookies in tomcat 7

```
    Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("someName", "someValue");
    userCookie.setMaxAge(99999999999); 
    userCookie.setPath("/");
    resp.addCookie(userCookie);
```

In the above example, resp is the HttpServletResponse. This code was tested and working for tomcat 7 and in JDK 1.7

Comment: Have you ever try with `setMaxAge(99999999999);` ? what age it will set ?

Comment: Link to the documentation is at: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29 It takes an int argument that corresponds to the life of the cookie in seconds. I just used an arbitrarily large number for a cookie I didn't want to expire soon

Comment: but if someone is new then give in some proper and understandable format like `(60*60*24) // 24 hours`.

Comment: Same code has been working fine in the Tomcat 6. I am afraid if I missed any configuration or not. I have checked with 60*60*24 in the age.

Comment: Could this be a browser side issue? I just tested it in my local env with JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 7, and it was working with a default Tomcat setup. I didn't have to edit any settings, simply installed and started it up. This leads me to believe that it's either a browser issue, or the response never makes it back to the browser? You may want to try uninstalling and reinstalling Tomcat 7, leaving everything as default as well.

Comment: Hi Mike,I have checked it and result I am gettiing. So to remove it I made some changes in my code but currently I am getting duplicate jsp:useBean id related issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Edit your question including any new parts, makes it easier to keep track and update my answer